# Returning different types from same method in Java interface

Tags: java, types, interface

Hi I wanted to define an interface where I have a method that returns an object of the class the implemented it. I know I may have to use something like " T" but I just can't get it right.

My idea is to have an interface implemented by some classes that has a static method to create that object from a Json string. I need it like this because in some cases I need to make custom deserialization. Do you know the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are looking for [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).  IE: `Something<T>` -> `Something<String>`, `Something<Integer>`, ect.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing you can do is

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
    T deserialize(String json);
}
```

and

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface<MyClass>
```

but you can't enforce implementation of static methods.

I recommend you to have a look at json libraries such as Jackson or Gson.